# Extract info using pagination- selenium bs4 python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

I am working with web scraping sales navigator. I was able to navigate to 1st page, scroll 8 times and extract all the names, titles using selenium and beautiful. below is the code.

```
driver.get(dm)
time.sleep(5)

time.sleep(5)
section = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='search-results-container']")
time.sleep(5)

counter = 0

while counter < 8:  # this will scroll 8 times
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;',
                                 section)
    counter += 1
    # add a timer for the data to fully load once you have scrolled the section

    time.sleep(7) # You might need to install time library to use this statement

src2 = driver.page_source
 
# Now using beautiful soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')

name_soup = soup.find_all('span', {'data-anonymize': 'person-name'})

names = []
for name in name_soup:
    names.append(name.text.strip())
```

However, there are 8 more pages and I need to extract all the names and append it to names list.

Please help

Comment: really hard to help if you don't share the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the logic I use for pagination is

```py
while True:
    ## PAGE SCRAPING CODE [ie, your current code]
    
    ## SEARCH FOR NEXT PAGE [button/link]
    ### IF NEXT PAGE --> click button or go to link
    ### NO NEXT PAGE --> BREAK
```

If you included the link you're trying to scrape, I might be able to give you a more specific answer. For example, [this](https://pastebin.com/d21q6mZ2) is a function I often use to scrape paginated data, although it's not meant to be for scrollable pages....